# Rotatelogs rotating log files mid log entry

Tags: apache-2.2, logging, logrotate, unix-shell

I have a c++ tool that outputs to STDOUT via printf i.e.

```
printf ("%s\n", logline);
```

I then pipe that to rotatelogs i.e.

```
tool | rotatelogs /tmp/logs/log_%s 60
```

Everything works great, but rotatelogs will rotate mid line so log file 1 has this json snippet:

```
{"tim
```

...and log file 2 will have:

```
e":1386088072}
```

Is there a way to encourage rotatelogs to rotate on line breaks?

Comment: k... I found the answer, but can't post for eight hours per server fault rules... Stay tuned.

Answer (score 2):

Simple answer: IO buffering. Turn it off by prefixing your command with:

```
stdbuf -i0 -o0 -e0
```

for example:

```
stdbuf -i0 -o0 -e0  tool | rotatelogs /tmp/logs/log_%s 60
```

Answer (score 0):

If the tool you have is your own or you have source of it, fix it first.  I assumed the tool is a daemon since it has log to rotate. (means it has long term lifecycle.)
to be a deamon, it must duplicate std* and close originals that related to tty. (it is somewhat off topic.)

Anyway, if you cannot touch the source, I recommend to use 'logrotate' instead of apache  'rotatelogs'. it is more general and well-made tool for generic purpose.

one of common problem of rotatelogs is, if process of rotatelogs is dead, all outputs are gone away. so try:

```
$ tool > logfile &
```

and create or edit logrotate.conf for logfile.